# SQL equivalent groupby in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

My table `collection` have the following columns

- collection_id (primary key)
- amount (`IntegerField`)
- date (`DateField`)

I need to get total amount collected per day in Django view. Must be equivalent to the following SQL query.

```
select sum(amount) from collection group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) and [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate).

```
Model.objects.values('date').annotate(sum=Sum('amount')).values_list('sum', flat=True)
```

**Explanation from docs**

> ### [Order of annotate() and values() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses)
>
> If the `values()` clause precedes the `annotate()`, the annotation will be computed using the grouping described by the `values()` clause.